# Connect to Azure SQL from on premise network

Tags: azure, security, azure-sql-server

We are developing a web API with Azure SQL for data persisting that is completely hosted on Azure. We need to push some data from on premise to Azure SQL. Our info-security team is not ready to open the port 1433 to provide outbound connectivity. What is the best approach to connect to Azure SQL from onprem securely. I did some research and found several ways to connect to on prem from Azure, but I need a secure connection to Azure Sql from on premise.

Comment: You can use VPN I assume? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-vnet-service-endpoint-rule-overview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Azure SQL Database service is only available through TCP port 1433. So you have to open the port 1433 to provide outbound connectivity.

To help secure your on-premises network environment, it’s a best practice to configure your on-premises firewall and allow outbound connections on port 1433 only to your **target SQL DB IP addresses** listed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-connectivity-architecture#azure-sql-database-gateway-ip-addresses). Read more explanation [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlcat/2017/10/06/secure-your-on-premises-network-outbound-connection-to-azure-sql-database-by-locking-down-target-ip-addresses/).

Moreover, Azure SQL Database forces all client connections to be encrypted. You could get more details from [an overview of Azure SQL Database security capabilities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-security-overview).

Comment: To connect from on-prem to Azure SQL Database, apart from opening port 1433 on Azure Firewall, what else should be done? Does it need Private Endpoint? Do you need to make other firewall rules?